# How to send bloburls to FileField in django

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, blob

I have the following bloburl blob:http://127.0.0.1:8000/99bbb97e-79ee-4ac5-b553-796e1f5e897e

How do I pass this to the Filefield in Django so that I can save this file ?

My models.py looks something like this

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    fileId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = file_upload_path)
    fileDescription = models.TextField()
```